# NullPointerExceptionm pleas help me

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am new to programming and want to ask for help because I am stuck on this task.
Clicking on the RecyclerView gets this error.
Below I will attach my code and hope for your help and solutions to the problem. Thank you

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.skreep.worko, PID: 24044
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skreep.worko/com.skreep.worko.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: workout_title must not be null
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: workout_title must not be null
       at com.skreep.worko.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.kt:32)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7894)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7881)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

**Workout Adapter**

```
package com.skreep.worko.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.skreep.worko.DetailActivity
import com.skreep.worko.R
import com.skreep.worko.databinding.ItemWorkoutBinding
import com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData

class WorkoutAdapter(var c:Context,var workoutList:ArrayList<WorkoutData>
):RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutAdapter.WorkoutViewHolder>()
{
   inner class WorkoutViewHolder(var v:ItemWorkoutBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v.root){}

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WorkoutViewHolder {
       val inflter = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
       val v = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemWorkoutBinding>(
           inflter, R.layout.item_workout,parent,
           false)
       return WorkoutViewHolder(v)

   }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkoutViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val newList = workoutList[position]
       holder.v.isWorkouts = workoutList[position]


       holder.v.root.setOnClickListener {
           val name = newList.name
           val description = newList.description
           val fullTime = newList.fullTime
           val workoutDesc = newList.workoutDesc
           val workoutName = newList.workoutName
           val workoutTime = newList.workoutTime


           val mIntent = Intent(c,DetailActivity::class.java)
           mIntent.putExtra("description",description)
           mIntent.putExtra("name",name)
           mIntent.putExtra("fullTime",fullTime)
           mIntent.putExtra("workoutDesc",workoutDesc)
           mIntent.putExtra("workoutName",workoutName)
           mIntent.putExtra("workoutTime",workoutTime)
           c.startActivity(mIntent)
       }
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return  workoutList.size
   }



}
```

**Detail Activity**

```
package com.skreep.worko


import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.skreep.worko.adapter.WorkoutAdapter
import com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_workout.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_workout_detail.*

class DetailActivity : BaseActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        val workoutIntent = intent
        val name = workoutIntent.getStringExtra("name")
        val description = workoutIntent.getStringExtra("description")
        val workoutName = workoutIntent.getStringExtra("workoutName")



        detail_name.text = name
        detail_desc.text = description
        workout_title.text = workoutName





    }


}
```

**Home Activity**

```
package com.skreep.worko

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.skreep.worko.adapter.WorkoutAdapter
import com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*


class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {

    lateinit var mDataBase:DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var workoutList:ArrayList<WorkoutData>
    private lateinit var mAdapter:WorkoutAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        workoutList = ArrayList()
        mAdapter = WorkoutAdapter(this, workoutList)

        recyclerworkoutList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerworkoutList.setHasFixedSize(true)




        recyclerworkoutList.adapter = mAdapter



        getWorkoutData()

    }

    private fun getWorkoutData() {

        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Workout")

        mDataBase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {

                        val workout = userSnapshot.getValue(WorkoutData::class.java)
                        workoutList.add(workout!!)

                    }

                    recyclerworkoutList.adapter = mAdapter

                }


            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@HomeActivity,
                        error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }


}
```

**XML Activity Detail**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="isData"
            type="com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData" />


    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        tools:context=".DetailActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_ic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:text="@{isData.name}"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="26sp"></TextView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detail_name"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/detail_name"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:text="@{isData.workoutDesc}"
            android:textColor="@color/lightgray">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_workout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Упражнения"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/workoutListDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_workout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:itemCount="1"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**Xml activity Home**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="isWorkouts"
            type="com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData" />


    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/welcome"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/welcome_description"
                    android:textColor="@color/desc_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/welcome" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerworkoutList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="40dp"
                    tools:itemCount="1"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_workout" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**item_workout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="isWorkouts"
            type="com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData" />


    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".SplashActivity">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/watch_ic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_watch"
                    app:tint="@color/darkblue"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvfulltime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:text="@{isWorkouts.fullTime}"
                    android:textSize="10sp"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                    android:text="@{isWorkouts.name}"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
                    android:textSize="24sp">

                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvtitle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="@{isWorkouts.description}"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                    android:textSize="12sp"></TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_next"

                    >

                </ImageView>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**item workout detail xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="isWorkout"
            type="com.skreep.worko.model.WorkoutData" />


    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".SplashActivity">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workout_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                    android:text="@{isWorkout.workoutName}"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
                    android:textSize="24sp"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workout_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workout_title"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workout_title"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                    android:text="@{isWorkout.workoutName}"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
                    android:textSize="12sp"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workout_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workout_title"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="@{isWorkout.workoutTime}"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
                    android:textSize="12sp">


                </TextView>


            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your activity_detail XML file is missing a Textview called `workout_title`

You have it in a different XML layout file workout_detail xml

Comment: What if I want a new recyclerview in DetailActivity?
What do I need to do?

Comment: It depends on how you want your app to be structured and what data you want to display. You can  have a Recyclerview in DetailActivity also, but remember it will need data to display!